# solutions of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ for cubic $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question :** Let $f(x)  =\dfrac{15-x^3}{7}$ then evaluate number of solutions for $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$.

**My Attempt :**

Since $f(x)=x$ gives atleast a subset of solutions we get atleast one solution.
Now,$$f(x)=f^{-1}(x)\iff f(f(x))=x$$
$$\dfrac{15-\left(\dfrac{15-x^3}{7}\right)^3}{7}=x$$
now how to guess other  solutions through this maybe?
One other idea I had was rough sketch of the function but that also seems to give $3$ solutions while the given answer is $5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand
$$\dfrac{15-\left(\dfrac{15-x^3}{7}\right)^3}{7}-x=0$$ remove the denominator to get
$$x^9-45 x^6+675 x^3-2401 x+1770=0$$ which nicely factors as
$$(x-2) (x-1) \left(x^3+7 x-15\right) \left(x^4+3 x^3-36
   x-59\right)=0$$

Show that the cubic has only one real root and the quartic two real roots.